# Strange behavior with printing a vector of structs

Tags: c++, printf

I want to print the values of a vector of structs to stdout.

The struct is defined as follows:

```
typedef struct CallStackEntry {
    DWORD64 base_address;
    DWORD64 return_address;
    char* file_name;
    char* symbol_name;
    DWORD line_number;

    CallStackEntry(DWORD64 ba, DWORD64 ra, char* f_name, char* s_name, DWORD ln) : 
                        base_address(ba), return_address(ra), file_name(new char[strlen(f_name)+1]), symbol_name(new char[strlen(s_name)+1]), line_number(ln)  
    {
        memcpy(file_name,f_name, strlen(f_name)+1);
        memcpy(symbol_name,s_name,strlen(s_name)+1);
    }

    } CS;
```

The following code works for printing:

```
void debuglib::StdOutLogger::logg(std::vector<CS> ces) {
    std::vector<CS>::iterator itr;
    for ( itr = ces.begin(); itr < ces.end(); ++itr )
    {       
        //printf("%08x", itr->return_address);
        printf("%s() called\nBaseaddress: 0x%08x\n", itr->symbol_name, itr->base_address);
        printf("Returnaddress: 0x08%x\n", itr->return_address);
        printf("In File: %s (Line: %d)\n\n", itr->file_name, itr->line_number);
    }
}
```

This code, however, does not work:

```
for ( itr = ces.begin(); itr < ces.end(); ++itr ) { 
    printf("%s() called\nBaseaddress: 0x%08x\nReturnaddress: 0x%08x\nInFile:%s (Line: %d)\n\n", itr->symbol_name, itr->base_address, itr->return_address, itr->file_name, itr->line_number);
}
```

In the second code list, filenumber and return_address is always 0 and filename gives me some cryptic characters.

Anyone have an idea what could cause this problem?

Comment: Can you show how **CS** is structured? What is **filenumer**?

Comment: These are some very nice hints! 
Unfortunally %lx doesnt fix the problem. But it has to be a problem with the size i guess like you already said.

Comment: It was the size! I changed DWORD64 to DWORD and its working now. But as the STACKFRAME structure contains a DWORD64 and I may port this to 64 bit it would be still nice to get it working with DWORD64. But I thank you very much guys already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well more likely than not the first one only *appears* to work. I suspect what's happening is that your `%x` to print the address is actually being passed a 64-bit pointer (are you compiling a 64-bit binary?). Then when you do it in separate calls it appears fine and prints 32 bits out of the address. When you run it all together `printf` gets confused because you lied about the amount of space used by each member.

g++ will warn at `-Wall` if you try to do this.

The C++ way to solve this is to use iostreams. Type-safe and easy.

If you want the C way with `printf` you'll probably want to use `%lx` instead, and make sure you cast your pointer to `long` so the type always lines up.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the definition of the `CS` struct, and without knowing about your C++ compiler and ABI settings, it's difficult to say for sure.

But the likeliest explanation is that you have a size issue.  For example, I suspect that `itr->base_address` is a 64-bit variable but `%08x` is expecting a 32-bit variable.  You probably need to use `%08lx` instead.

Comment: %08lx is also likely 32-bit because it expects `unsigned long int`.